# Error in is.finite(x) when plotting a heatmap with soccermatics

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the code example from soccermatics (https://github.com/JoGall/soccermatics) to plot a Heatmap from Passes of France in R but recieved an Error. How can I fix this?

I already tried to deinstall ggplot2 and installed it with CRAN, but the error remained. All the other necessary packages are in my opinion installed.

```
statsbomb %>%
     filter(type.name == "Pass" & team.name == "France") %>% 
       soccerHeatmap(x = "location.x", y = "location.y",
       title = "France (vs Argentina, 30th June 2016)", 
       subtitle = "Passing heatmap")
```

I expected a heatmap but the result was this error:
Error in is.finite(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'

UPDATE: The data is imported directly from statsbomb via github. A sample size of this event data looks like this:

ID - Index - Period -  Timestamp - Minute - Second - Posession - Off camera etc. 
0040b09e-e63e-4232-97c3-16e668a1db65 - 2304 - 2 - 00:35:05.320 - 80 - 5 - 126 - FALSE

Comment: Please post a sample of the dataset `statsbomb` so that we can reproduce the results.

Comment: The error sounds as though you might have a list column in your data, but you need to post a sample of your data to say anything more definitively (ideally with `dput(head(statsbomb))`